# How to find default drive of windows using batch file

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to find the drive in which windows is installed using batch file.

for example

```
@echo off
set /p a=enter=
if %a%==%windows% goto c
if %a%==d goto d    
:c
echo Windows drive
pause
:d
echo Not Windows Drive
pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=\" %%D in ("%windir%") do echo %%D
```

Comment: it seems the code is case sensitive, its give different output for c and C. any way to rectify it

Comment: with `IF /I "string" equ "STRING"` you can make case insensitive comparsions .

Answer (score 8):

This is stored in the variable `%SystemDrive%`

```
echo %SystemDrive%
```

But you probably want to use %SystemRoot% instead which includes the drive **and** the directory:

```
echo %SystemRoot%
```

Comment: hey thanks but how i introduce it in if statement, it seems %a%=%SystemDrive% not working properly

Comment: use `if %a% EQU %SystemDrive%`. Btw: %SystemDrive% is `C:`, %a% is probably `C` only. If yes, write `if %a%: EQU %SystemDrive%`.

Comment: I think that %SystemDrive% points only to the bootable drive and windows could be on other derive.Bit I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 4):

A few characters shorter. :)

```
for %%a in ("%windir%") do echo %%~da
```

Or

```
echo %windir:~0,2%
```

Comment: @npocmaka  Thanks.  It's often easy to think of an enhancement when someone else has provided the first steps.

Answer (score 0):

This will also return the drive:

```
for /f %%a in ('echo %comspec% ^| choice /c:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz /n') do set driv=%%a
```

Or even shorter

```
echo %comspec:~0,1%
Rem Also with the colon
echo %comspec:~0,2%
```

Comment: Edit now gives only C

Answer (score 0):

Here Is A Small Script To Find System Drives & Assigned Letter !

Also Open The System Drive.

```
@ECHO OFF 

TITLE [FIND SYSTEM DRIVE AND ASSIGNED  LETTER]

COLOR 2

MODE CON: COLS=55 LINES=6

:Start

ECHO.

ECHO SYSTEM DRIVE MAIN : %SYSTEMDRIVE%

ECHO SYSTEM DRIVE ASSIGNED ALPHABET : %SYSTEMDRIVE:~0,-1%

ECHO.

ECHO PRESS ANY KEY TO EXIT !

PAUSE >NUL

START %SYSTEMDRIVE%

EXIT
```

`%SYSTEMDRIVE%` What this command does is find the System Drive

For Example. My System Drive is `C:`

`%SYSTEMDRIVE:~0,-1%` What this command does is find the System Drive and remove the last letter from it

For Example. `C`

I hope that you find it helpful !